# Print text multiple times in Brainfuck

Tags: loops, brainfuck

I tried out this hello world program in Brainfuck. How can I print the text multiple number of times?
Here's my code:

```
+++++++[>++++++++++ <- ] >++.>++++++[>++++++++++ <- ] >+++++++++.>+++++++[>++++++++++ <- ] >++++++..>+++++++[>++++++++++ <- ] >+++++++++.>+++[>++++++++++ <-]>++. >++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+++++++.>+++++++[>++++++++++<-] >+++++++++.>++++++++[>++++++++++ <-]>++.>+++++++[>++++++++++ <- ] >++++++.>++++++[>++++++++++ <-]>++++++++.>+++[>++++++++++<-]>++.>+++[>++++++++++<-]>+++.>+++[>++++++++++<-]>+++.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's think of a 5 character long word like "hello".

So if you want it to print those 5 characters 3 times you could have a code like this:

```
,>,>,>,>,>+++[<<<<<.>.>.>.>.>-]
```

Let me explain the code:

The first part of the code is the input part:

```
,>,>,>,>,
```

Then you initialize a variable containing the information that you want to print it 3 times.

```
>+++
```

Then you have the loop which goes back to the start, prints out those 5 characters, and goes to the variable and decrement it.

```
[<<<<< //goes back

.>.>.>.>. //print out

>-]  //decrement
```

If you got the idea, then you can easily improve the code by e.g. putting more loops in it, I just wanted to show you a simple idea.

Answer (score 4):

A more general answer is as follows.

Let's say you want to print the text 5 times (we'll call this *counter*)

```
+++++ >
```

and then import characters until a \n (= 10) is given.

```
----- -----[+++++ +++++ >, ----- -----]
```

The array now looks like *< counter, 0, string >*. Finally, we place the pointer at *counter*.

```
<[<]<
```

We finish by printing the string multiple times.

```
[       while (counter) {
>>[.>]    print string
<[<]<-    counter--
]       }
```